# Sharepoint Flow not working after search

Tags: flow

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?   I have a button on a list that fires up a flow...all works fine.  When i do a search, the button exists but now does not fire up the flow???  I have read else where this is known but could not see a fix.   The list is modern fyi.  Thx in advance.

Json..

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Express Request this Software",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"1176e4f1-d4bc-4174-be23-03cecb3ed1ca\", \"headerText\":\"Confirm you want to request this software and that you have budget holder approval already\",\"runFlowButtonText\":\"Click Here To Confirm Request\"}"
      },
      "style": {
        "background-color": "blue",
        "color": "white",
        "display": "=if(([$VisibleButton] == true) && ([$Status] != 'Rejected') ,'','none')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "href": "https://myserver/altiris/softwareportal/portal/",
        "target": "https://myserver/altiris/softwareportal/portal/"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "button",
          "txtContent": "Request this Software",
          "style": {
            "background-color": "purple",
            "color": "white",
            "display": "=if(([$VisibleButton] == false) && ([$Status] != 'Rejected') ,'','none')"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Flow looks like this....
[image]

Search done like this
[image]

Comment: Please provide some more details. How did you configure the flow, how did you add the button, how do you do the search. Screenshots are a plus!

Comment: Here's the flow but I think the issue is either the JSon behind the button or SP online itself.

Comment: Can't upload the flow but here is the JSON

Comment: Sorry added Json and Flow to OP.   If i do a filter then the button still works and runs the flow so just the search seems to kill the flow button execution

Comment: @RuneSperre your help is appreciated

Comment: Ah, starting to see how this is tied together now. Your flow is probably ok - the problem is that the button action is not executed when the list is filtered through search ( i was able to reproduce )

Comment: I think you have found a bug - you should open a service request with Microsoft to report this! It is only when searching the executeFlow action stops working -- when filtering/sorting/etc it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Rune.  I was hoping I hadn’t oh well let’s see if MS support can fix it